# ¿Es la reputación de Meta y del sitio principal la misma? ¿Y las medallas?

Tags: soporte, meta, reputación, medallas

¿Cómo funciona exactamente Stack Overflow Meta?

Veo que al participar en esta sección del sitio se me han asignado nuevas medallas pero que la puntuación es la misma que la de Stack Overflow en español.

Por otro lado veo que las notificaciones las mantengo en ambos sitios conjuntamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se explica aqui: [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

> Los votos en meta no afectan tu reputación; tu reputación en meta es la misma que tu reputación en Stack Overflow en español (sincronizada cada hora), sin embargo las medallas **sí** están separadas. Debes tener una reputación de 5 para participar en meta.

Las notificaciones se comparten en toda la red.

Comment: Como nota, los votos en meta usualmente significan que se esta de acuerdo o en desacuerdo con una publicacion...